# What is the best use of a variable when required by multiple methods

Tags: c#

I'm using XmlManager to 
do xml manipulations in several methods in a class.where I should declare XmlManager variable ?
1.locally within each method and do intialization.
2 declare at globally and initiate at the method level

Comment: This question probably belongs at Programmers, not Stack Overflow. http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Question moved to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is, in this question, there's absolutely NO difference whatsoever because there's neither performance gain nor significant design issues.

Maybe if the question is put into context there could be reason to choose one approach over the other, but as it stands now. None of the approach is better than the other one